# joomla URL rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, joomla, url-rewriting, joomla-extensions

I am Using Joomla 2.5, I am using extension Enmass for site, I have make SEO URL from Admin but URL will show like this

http://abc.com/index.php/component/enmasse/deal/view/8/evo_in_line_foldable_scooter_black

I need to rewrite this URL to

http://abc.com/evo_in_line_foldable_scooter_black.html

I had tried to change in .htaccess but i didnt success.

If any one has idea for this please let me know.

Comment: Try putting the rules, which you don't include in your question, after this line `## Begin - Custom redirects` in the Joomla .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a menu item within Joomla for this Enmass view and it will create this URL.

The URL you see is created by the Joomla JRoute class if no menu item (Itemid) is passed together with the raw URL.

Also the extension can set up its own routing rules with the router.php file (/components/com_enmasse/router.php).